# deploy Laravel to Openshift for beginners

Tags: php, laravel, openshift

I'm a beginner of openshift, already did some tutorials on learn.openshift.com and
I understand Docker. 
Seems basic, but how can I easily deploy laravel on openshift?

Larvel needs a PHP webserver and a database. 
(I've searched on stackoverflow but the solutions are 4 years old. I've searched online, but those solutions are only about the old versions of openshift.)

thanks a lot in advance!